# How to find the sequence of numbers in a txt file and save it with CMD of Windows 10?

Tags: string, cmd

I have a file `authen.txt` being in real a file with binary data because of containing also bytes with the decimal values 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 15 and 22. The binary bytes in text block below are replaced by other characters for better display by the browsers using following table with hexadecimal values:

```
01 ... B1 ... ± ... two occurrences
03 ... B3 ... ³ ... two occurrences
05 ... B5 ... µ ... seven occurrences
06 ... B6 ... ¶ ... one occurrence
08 ... B8 ... ¸ ... two occurrences
0B ... BB ... » ... two occurrences
0C ... BC ... ¼ ... one occurrence
0F ... BF ... ¿ ... three occurrences
16 ... C6 ... Æ ... one occurrence
```

I want to separate the sequence of numbers like `1000xxxxxx ..` and save them into a file `uid.txt`. I use CMD on Windows 10.

My file `authen.txt` with the binary bytes replaced as listed above:

```
±   ¸µ ¶secret  0a96f39c64da3faebb9a5b8f4c0df70dµ ¼access_token ÊEAAAAUaZA8jlABAFRhsSpAZCpSHZBiEx8zr1MNlyO6EDF84yEq3f4HYck0Pobx3gLfRVTztwsSuzQkHkRGZAdK4WOZCklyyG7kYTGqiyZB369bfCfDEFDFlzXOiqDkaME97X5ZAZCGYlM0vTiZAb5A3uJRdtIeeJZCkXK9xhmdFXJhyQgi0OgpFdFVZAOBZAzXznU40oZD  »is_imported±µ ¸username ¿100067536142472µ ³uid ¿100067536142472µ ¿analytics_claim 5hmac.AR3hvKMOVcvLUwDFoj3xtLU-D1nQnr2ROtWNIazCnr0bm7Raµ »session_key .5.cmnvGeQeV4V_sA.1620719120.29-100067536142472µ Æsession_cookies_string³$[{"name":"c_user","value":"100067536142472","expires":"Wed, 11 May 2022 07:45:20 GMT","expires_timestamp":1652255120,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true},{"name":"xs","value":"29:cmnvGeQeV4V_sA:2:1620719120:-1:-1","expires":"Wed, 11 May 2022 07:45:20 GMT","expires_timestamp":1652255120,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"fr","value":"1A1PLzebTFjuxoVmE.AWWi1-XI-VNYw9B4ZPSpMkCXq5I.BgmjYQ.kW.AAA.0.0.BgmjYQ.AWULPGUfH58","expires":"Mon, 09 Aug 2021 07:45:19 GMT","expires_timestamp":1628495119,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true},{"name":"datr","value":"BjaaYN3Xkt5USKMtDNwku5cs","expires":"Thu, 11 May 2023 07:45:20 GMT","expires_timestamp":1683791120,"domain":".facebook.com","path":"/","secure":true,"httponly":true}]"
```

There are no null bytes in the file.

[Content of file authen.txt as displayed by Windows Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oSJw.png)

Answer (score 1):

This works when the file is exactly formatted as in your example (even when it's not a pure textfile):

```
@echo off & setlocal 
<authen.txt set /p var=
set "var=%var:*"value":=%"
REM set "var=%var:*uid =%"
>uid.txt echo/%var:~1,12%
```

Usually, we use a `for` loop with proper tokens and delims to extract a subtext from a file or string. Due to some special characters (lower than `20` hex), this fails.

Instead, this copies the (first ~1k chars of (limitation of `set /p`, but that's enough here)) file into a variable. It then deletes everything from the beginning until (including) the string `"value":` (or `uid`  - pick your choice). Then it simply extracts the relevant substring (we know it's length) and writes it to the output file.

This looks surprisingly short, but there is no verification or check in place. Also any Null-Bytes may stop it from working properly (you claimed there are none).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the file with the authentication data is a binary file containing multiple strings with a byte for the length of a string left to each string and some other binary data.

So it is not really a text file with [characters encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) using a [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) like [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252) or a [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) encoding like [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) or [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). But it is possible to process the authentication data with Windows command processor as long as the file does not contain null bytes. It would be nevertheless better to use a more modern script interpreter than the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` for processing such files. `cmd` has no built-in support for string functions. The Windows command processor is designed for running commands and executables and definitely not for enhanced processing of data in files.

Here is a partly commented batch file code to get the universal identifier number `100067536142472` written into a file `uid.txt`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "authen.txt" goto EndBatch
rem Read the data from a file and assign it to an environment variable.
set "DataFile="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("authen.txt") do set "DataFile=%%I"
if not defined DataFile goto EndBatch
rem Delete the output file on already existing.
del "uid.txt" 2>nul
rem Enable delayed expansion for safer processing the authentication data.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:LoopUID
set "DataTemp=!DataFile:*uid =!"
if "!DataFile!" == "!DataTemp!" endlocal & goto EndBatch
:LoopStart
for /F delims^=0123456789^ eol^= %%I in ("!DataTemp:~0,1!") do set "DataTemp=!DataTemp:~1!" & goto LoopStart
set "DataUID="
:LoopEnd
set "DataUID=%DataUID%%DataTemp:~0,1%"
set "DataTemp=!DataTemp:~1!"
for /F delims^=0123456789^ eol^= %%I in ("!DataTemp:~0,1!") do goto OutputUID
goto LoopEnd
:OutputUID
echo !DataUID!>>"uid.txt"
set "DataFile=!DataTemp!" & goto LoopUID

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

**Note:** The **FOR** loop at top is designed to get the **last line** assigned to the environment variable `DataFile`. That means if one of the binary bytes has by chance the decimal value 10 (hexadecimal 0A) which is in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table a line-feed (LF), the environment variable `DataFile` is defined with the data after last byte with decimal value 0A. This could result in `uid` number not extracted from the file if the file contains one or more bytes with decimal value 10 after the block with `uid`.

The code is written to extract all `uid` values in last line in file `authen.txt` line by line to `uid.txt`.

The command line after `:LoopUID` defines the environment variable `DataTemp` with the string assigned to the environment variable `DataFile` with having removed everything from the beginning to the end of first occurrence of the string `uid`  using a string substitution.

The loop named `LoopUID` is exited on string assigned to `DataTemp` is equal the string assigned to `DataFile` because of there is no more the string `uid`  in the string assigned currently to the environment variable `DataFile`.

The loop named `LoopStart` is for finding the start of the universal identifier number. It analyzes if the first character of the string assigned to variable `DataTemp` is not a digit character in which case it removes this character from `DataTemp` and runs the **FOR** command once again. Otherwise the UID extraction starts on first character in range `0` to `9` found in the string after `uid` .

The loop named `LoopEnd` is for appending one digit character after the other to the string assigned to the environment variable `DataUID` from the string assigned to the variable `DataTemp` being also removed from this string until the first character of `DataTemp` is not anymore a digit character.

The determined identifier number is output with redirecting this output into the file `uid.txt`.

Please note that the code is definitely not fail safe. There are several possible use cases on which this code could result in wrong behavior depending on the authentication data in the file. It would be really better to use VBscript or PowerShell for this task and not a batch file interpreted by the Windows command processor.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Please read also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>>` and `2>nul`.